Stats not available in Google Ads scripts
I am trying to set up some automated rules for a client. I want a script that can increase daily campaign budgets if certain results are met. More specifically, I want budget increased if they are limited by budget and their target ROAS is met. I am have problems doing this because metrics like conversion value, lost impression share (budget), impression share etc does not seem to be available.
I have tried several different ways. I was hoping that campaign status, impression share, conversion value etc was possible to use in scripts, but so far I have not found a solution for this. Is there any way possible to use these metrics?
